# wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); - как убрать версию Wordpress при подключении скрипта

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру.

Вопрос следующий. В файле functions.php темы имеется такой код

```
if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
```

Который выводит в html `https://site.ru/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=4.7.3`

Как избавиться от `?ver=4.7.3` ?

Я пробовал так `wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply', array (), null, true );` но не сработало :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам это не нужно, но сделать можно так:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/comment-reply.js', array('jquery'), null));
```

Четвертый аргумент - номер версии. Если `null`, то `?ver=` не выводится.

Comment: Спасибо. Только 'comment-reply' надо переименовать во что-то другое, в ином случае так и будет отображаться префикс.